# FindBugs: Detect invocation of Object.hashCode()

Tags: java, static-analysis, findbugs

If an object doesn't implement it's own `hashCode()` method, then it will use the default implementation `Object.hashCode()` (provided there's no superclass in between). `Object.hashCode()` doesn't guarantee the same hash code to be generated in different JVM instance. We are having some problems because of this in a clustered environment.

Additionally to some fixes that we applied, we would like to have static analysis detect this case. We are already using FindBugs, but unfortunatly I have no experience extending the default ruleset.

I've done some research and I know that you can implement your own custom detectors, but I have not found much documentation on how to do this.

I guess my questions are:

- Before I invest too much work here, is this approach reasonable, can FindBugs do this?
- What's the best resources to get me started writing custom detectors?

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 5):

Findbugs has some checks for hashCode already: (see also http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html )

- HE_EQUALS_NO_HASHCODE
- HE_EQUALS_USE_HASHCODE
- HE_HASHCODE_NO_EQUALS
- HE_HASHCODE_USE_OBJECT_EQUALS
- HE_INHERITS_EQUALS_USE_HASHCODE (this might be of interest for your case)

If those are not sufficient for you, they might be a good starting point for creating a custom detector.

UPDATE. The source code of the detectors can be found in https://code.google.com/p/findbugs/source/browse/findbugs/src/java/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/ and the other packages of that repo.

Answer (score 1):

You may try it the other way around:

Add a hashCode() method to all your (entity like) classes. The nonexistance of that method can easily be verified with findbugs. The implementation would look something like:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() { 
 throw new UnsupportedOperationException("hashcode() not supported.");
}
```

By that you can ensure that there is no Object.hashCode() "fallback" - that class will not be used in HashMaps, HashTables, HashSets or any other situation where hashCode() will be called.

Answer (score -1):

I think that will be really difficult (if it's even possible). But I have two other things you could try to find places where classes should override `hashCode()`:

1. At least Netbeans has a hint for "overrides equals but not hashCode" that could help a little.
2. Place a breakpoint on `Object.hashCode()` and run a more or less representative testset.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, I think FindBugs already checks you first suggestion, the second one is difficult to do, because we have a lot of seperate (different processes) services working together in a quite complex system. Also I'd really like to have this automated to prevent the same bug happening again in the future.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to find ALL classes which do not implement getHashCode(), couldn't you just use a simple text-search / grep approach ?

Just search all Files with ending .java in your project which do not contain the string "public int getHashCode", would be fairly easy to write a script for this. You can e.g. just use a simple search-tool to find all java-files containing the text and substract this list from a list of all .java files. The resulting list will have all .java files which do not override getHashCode()

Comment: I dont really want all classes to implement hashCode(), I want to not permit calling through to Object.hashCode(). There's lot's of classes that don't need hashCode()...